# How to get the same Id, Value or Text even after DOM changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am wondering if an id of a div is 1 and someone changed the id to 34, when someone clicks on it the attr('id') still equals to 1 even after change instead of 34. Apologize for my english thank you.

```
        $(document).on('click','.edit_btn:eq(0)',function(){
            var itm_id = $(this).siblings('input').attr('id');
            alert(itm_id);

        });
```

Want the id to equal to 1 instead of 34 even after someone changes it with DOM

Comment: Use a backup class and the dynamic ID, then always get the element by the class. If the elements ID is **1** and changed to **2**, it's class would still be the same.

Comment: @Raymond well if they go to trouble of changing the id nothing preventing them changing the class either

Comment: @charlietfl is correct!
What is the actual requirement for this?

Comment: Not much you can do to prevent people modifying things in browser dev tools. Just make sure to always validate anything sent to server

Comment: @charlietfl You can set a MutationObserver and listen to any changes to the attribute.

Comment: @jdc91 You must be my professor. Anyways, in theory there is really nothing we can do to stop someone. Even when I think about the interval checker, you could disable scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MutationObserver to see if the attribute changes, then change it back. Make sure when you change it back, it knows to ignore that change. Or you will lag the browser out. Note, that this could be disabled by any monkey with dev tools.

Don't rely on the client.

```js
let i = 0;
const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

let e = document.querySelector('#test');
setInterval(() => {
  i++;
  // Change
  e.setAttribute('id', i);
}, 1000); // Loop Sleep

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      if (e.id !== 'test') {
        let previous = e.id;
        // Revert
        e.setAttribute('id', 'test');
        console.log('Changed to test from', previous)
      }

    }
  });
});

observer.observe(e, {
  attributes: true
});
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```